# Javafx table in Swing

Tags: java, swing, javafx, tableview

I have a Swing application. I want to use JavaFx in my project. I can not add a TableView into a panel in Jframe. Please help me to **add a TableView into a panel in Jframe.**

I have a Swing application. I want to use JavaFx in my project. I can not add a TableView into a panel in Jframe. Please help me to **add a TableView into a panel in Jframe.**

```
   TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
   final ObservableList<Person> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
        new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
        new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
        new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
        new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com"));
    final HBox hb = new HBox();
    private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
        this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public void setFirstName(String fName) {
        firstName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public void setLastName(String fName) {
        lastName.set(fName);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email.get();
    }

    public void setEmail(String fName) {
        email.set(fName);
    }
}









public NewJFrame1() {
    initComponents();
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());


    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final TextField addFirstName = new TextField();
    addFirstName.setPromptText("First Name");
    addFirstName.setMaxWidth(firstNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addLastName = new TextField();
    addLastName.setMaxWidth(lastNameCol.getPrefWidth());
    addLastName.setPromptText("Last Name");
    final TextField addEmail = new TextField();
    addEmail.setMaxWidth(emailCol.getPrefWidth());
    addEmail.setPromptText("Email");

    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: gray; -fx-text-fill: white;");
    addButton.getStyleClass().add("button1");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new Person(
                    addFirstName.getText(),
                    addLastName.getText(),
                    addEmail.getText()));
            addFirstName.clear();
            addLastName.clear();
            addEmail.clear();
        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addFirstName, addLastName, addEmail, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    PopupMenu s;
    JFXPanel jf = new JFXPanel();
    jf.add(table);

    jPanel1.add(jf);





}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the JFXPanel class from the JavaFX Library?

Comment: Yes, but I can not.

Comment: Why can’t you use the JFXPanel?

Comment: I use this but don`t work:  JFXPanel jf = new JFXPanel();
        jf.add(table);

Comment: please add your code snippets to your question, I need to be able to see what you have tried.

Comment: I add my code to question

Comment: Im having trouble finding where you declare what “table” is. Can you point out where the table is instantiated?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edit it

Comment: Your problem is you can’t add a TableView straight to a JFXPanel, you have to populate the JFXPanel with a scene first, then add the TableView.

Comment: Thanks for your helo ; )

Comment: So much unnecessary typing to answer such a simple question. You are welcome, but please format your question properly the FIRST time next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a `TableView` directly to a `JFXPanel`. You must first populate the `JFXPanel` with a `Scene`, and THEN you can add the `TableView` to the `Scene`

Cheers!